# How can I speed up the first file open from NERDTree in MacVim?

Tags: vim, macvim

Tried on both macvim snapshot 53 and the recent 55.

When I open a Rails directory with "mvim .", it starts up NERD_Tree. When I open any file, it takes about 5 secs to load on my macbook pro intel core duo 2 2.5GHz 4GB of RAM.

I'm mostly using https://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles as my vimfile/plugins.

How can I find what's causing the long load time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From VIM 7, plugins can load in 2 stages to make startup quicker. As I understand it, the plugins get registered straight away but the bulk of the plugin is only loaded as needed. If you're using a set of plugins that apply to any filetype, or are ruby/rails specific then when you load the first file there will be a delay like that. I have the same problem, I've confirmed its nothing to do with NerdTree, opening with ":e" has the same delay.